# Copy every n of cells every n of columns and paste in a new row, for every row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

[image]

In the above example, I'd like to start in F2, and copy F2,G2 and H2, then paste those values in a new row.I'd like to continue to do that until the last column at the end of the row.I would also be ok if I started in C2 and had to paste in a new sheet. I'd like to continue doing this until the last row is empty.

I've found this, but it only copies every 3rd cell, not a range:

```
Sub CopyNthData()
Dim i As Long, icount As Long
Dim ilastrow As Long
Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

Set wsFrom = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set wsTo = Sheets("Sheet1")
ilastrow = wsFrom.Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row
icount = 1

For i = 1 To ilastrow Step 3
wsTo.Range("B" & icount) = wsFrom.Range("B" & i) 
icount = icount + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

I assume the best way to do this is through VBA, but I'm a bit of a novice in VBA. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: I added some code I found, but it's not exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: It's only copying every 3rd cell because of the `Step 3` if you change that to `Step 1` it'll copy every cell.

Comment: I understand the step issue, but I need to copy 3 values, not just one. And pasting in a new sheet is and probably preferred. I found the Range.Copy method [Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy], but I don't want a set range, it needs to be variable

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your comment correctly, you just want to copy a larger range?

You can do that similar to:

```
stepCt = 3
lr = stepCt-1
For i = 1 To ilastrow Step stepCt
    With wsTo
       .Range(.Cells(icount,2),.Cells(icount+lr,2)) = wsFrom.Range(wsFrom.Cells(i,2),wsFrom.Cells(i+lr,2)) 
    End With
    icount = icount + stepCt 'Accounts for multiple ROWS
Next i
```

Can do similar to multiple columns, where instead of adding `lr` (last row) to the row argument of `Cells()` you can add to the column argument of `Cells()`.  The use of `stepCt` wouldn't be necessary in that case.

---

**Edit1:**

Changing to show columns, not rows, as the original question changed from asking for copying `F2, F3, & F4` to `F2, G2, & H2`.

```
For i = 1 To ilastrow
    With wsTo
       .Range(.Cells(icount,6),.Cells(icount,8)).Value = wsFrom.Range(wsFrom.Cells(i,6),wsFrom.Cells(i,8)).Value 
    End With
    icount = icount + 1
Next i
```

Comment: this copies b1:b3 and doesn't paste anywhere, I'll try to edit it

Comment: @mcadamsjustin this would do `.value = .value`, same as you had written into your code, not copy/paste.  Based on your example text "*I'd like to start in F2, and copy F2,G2 and H2, then paste those values in a new row.*" this would do similar, though I used your code choice of `Columns("B")`, aka `2`.  What was your `iLastRow` when you ran?

Comment: @mcadamsjustin just updated as I noticed your scope changed in the edit.  Stated F2, F3, & F4 to copy when i originally posted.  I used columns 6 to 8 for each the source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but this will paste all data in a range starting from F2 into a new sheet starting in C2.

```
Sub CopyNthData1()
    Dim Source As Range
    Set Source = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(("F2"), Range("F2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    Source.Copy
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Set DestRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
    DestRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Comment: this copies f2:n4 and pastes it onto seperate rows in sheet2. That's a good start, but I just want to copy 3 cells at a time and paste them, not the entire row. So copy f2:h2, then I2:k2. I need to edit my question, I stated it incorrectly in my initial post